# Single Page Application and Inline Fancybox not working properly

Tags: html, fancybox-2, single-page-application, durandal

I'm trying to make a SPA and use the Hot Towel template with Durandal. So far I have successfully added a Fancybox to my spa and it shows a image

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8486/8225588056_d229e8fe57_b.jpg" title="Porth Nanven (MarcElliott)">
        <img src="IMAGEPATH" alt="" />
    </a>


$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
            openEffect: 'elastic',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            helper: {
                title: {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                thumbs: {
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50
                }
            }
        });

        $('#label').click(function () {
            $('#inline').fancybox();
        });

    });
```

This is working not that properly but okay;)

Now I want to have a own inline in the fancybox like this:

```
<div id="inline" style="display:none;width:500px;">
        <p>
            <a id="add_paragraph" title="Add" class="button button-blue" href="javascript:;">Add new paragraph</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
</div>
```

Now when I click: `<a class="fancybox-thumb" href="#inline">Inline</a>`, I do get the fancybox with my info. But the url is set back to localhost:2321/#inline so I'm redirected back to home but I do see the fancybox.

How can I solve this, so that the fancybox is shown an the right page in my SPA and stays there?

Comment: What does `$('#label').click()` do? I don't think you need it because that is binding fancybox to the target of `.fancybox-thumb` ... you don't need to bind `#inline` to fancybox because is your target item.

Comment: Thats from something else but doesn't do anything in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working ;)

THis is what I did,

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox-link">Inline</a>    

    <div style="display: none">
        <div id="inlineContent" style="width:1000px;">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>

            <p>
                <a id="add_paragraph" title="Add" class="button button-blue" href="javascript:;">Add new paragraph</a>
                &nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("a.fancybox-link").click(function (e) {
            $.fancybox({
                content: $('#inlineContent').html(),
                type: 'inline'             
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Bye bye

Comment: That was a way more complicated than it should ... but at least you are happy with that.

Comment: @JFK Do you know a better way? ;)

Comment: see my answer for the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If you already initialized fancybox

```
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    helper: {
        title: {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        thumbs: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        }
    }
});
```

then you can use the same script for both your *images* AND your *inline* content, so the link for the image(s) :

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8486/8225588056_d229e8fe57_b.jpg" title="Porth Nanven (MarcElliott)"><img alt="" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8338/8224516167_bc7a5f6699_m.jpg" /></a>
```

and the link for the *inline* content :

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" data-fancybox-type="inline" href="#inline">Inline</a>
```

Notice that we added the `data-fancybox-type="inline"` attribute to define the `type` of content for this specific item.

Your *inline* html structure can remain the same :

```
<div id="inline" style="display:none;width:500px;">
    <p>
       <a id="add_paragraph" title="Add" class="button button-blue" href="javascript:;">Add new paragraph</a>
&nbsp; <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DQXrQ/)**