# Reapply bindings after Fancybox with knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, fancybox-2, durandal

I'm trying to accomplish the result that when a user clicks a link an inline fancybox opens with html in it. When the user entered a value and hits enter it should update (knockout) my viewmodel and the fancy box should face a way.

THis is my code so far, I know I need to reapply mybindings but can't figure out how.

HTML:

```
<div style="display:none">
        <div id="inlineManufacturerAdder">
            <div style="width:1000px;">
                <!-- In deze div alle content -->
                <h2>Add new Manufacturer2</h2>
                <p>

                    <form data-bind="submit: vm.addManufacturer">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: vm.newManufacturer, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="New Manufacturer">
                    </form>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript (typescript):

```
export function viewAttached() {
    $("a.fancybox-link-add-manufacturer").click(function (e) {
        $.fancybox({
            content: $('#inlineManufacturerAdder').html(), //this is where it goes wrong, it gets the content and forgets the bindings I guess!
            type: 'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

If I use the div (that is being set to display:none) in a normal way so without the fancybox everything works just fine.

What should I do? I'm using Durandal!

Comment: I know that i'm not answering your question but, why are you trying to use fancybox? Durandal has functions to show modal dialogs and even it has documentation that shows how to change the aspect ( http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals/ ), What do you need from fancybox that can't be done with durandal?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to reapply the bindings. Just don't pass in the innerHTML contents, rather pass in the element node (or jquery instance) to fancy box.

EG: Instead of:

`content: $('#inlineManufacturerAdder').html()`

just do:

`content: $('#inlineManufacturerAdder')`

[Update]

OR something a long these lines:

```
<a href="#inlineManufacturerAdder" class="fancybox-link-add-manufacturer" >Click me</a>
<div id="inlineManufacturerAdder" data-bind="html: msg"></div>

<script>
$(".fancybox-link-add-manufacturer").fancybox();
</script>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/r83XF/2/

Comment: If I do that my typescript is not compiling anymore. It says: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. http://postimg.org/image/wu0rfagd3/

Comment: Sorry that didn't do the trick, because if the link has a href its sents back to home! --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503981/single-page-application-and-inline-fancybox-not-working-properly

Comment: You're not using the fancybox plugin correctly. The reason why it 'goes back home' is because you've bound a click handler on the link when you're suppose to init fancybox on page load. Refer back to my example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/r83XF/2/show See the URL hash does not change when you click on the click. Also see I have not bound any custom click handlers.

Comment: badsyntax, when I removed the .html(), the binding seems to be fine!, Thank you very much , IMO, the above answer should be accepted.